# vector space direct sum projection

Tags: vector-spaces

Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space.
(a) Let U, W be subspaces such that V = U ⊕ W. Let P : V → V be the projection on U along W, and let Q : V → V be the projection on W along U.

(i) Show that Q = Iv − P. (ii) Show that P2 = P, that Q2 = Q and that PQ = QP = 0

the definition of projection:
P : V → V P(v) = w
there is a companion linear transformation Q : V → V which is the projection of V onto w along u

Comment: Does "along" here mean the same as "of" ...? And what is "IV"  supposed to mean? If you added some self work it would also help to understand you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

a.) $\ V=U\oplus W\ $ means that all vectors $v\in V$ can be uniquely written in the form $u+w$ for certain $u\in U,\ w\in W$ vectors. 
Concesquently, a map $V\to V$ can be defined on elements of $V$ using this decomposition.

b.) $P$ will map $(u+w) \mapsto u$. 
(This 'projection *along $W$*' is to mean $\ker P=W$, i.e. all vectors of $W$ are projected to the origin.) 
Similarly, $Q$ maps $(u+w)\mapsto w$.

c.) $P^2$ is the map $P$ applied twice. 
Note that if $u\in U$, then its decomposition is $u+0$, and $Pu=u$.